# Call to a member function isClient() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**I am getting below error**

> Call to a member function isClient() on a non-object

**When is it occurring ?**

I have a Post route `http://localhost/auth/logout` When I press the logout button then this action method gets called.

**Below is my User model**

```
class User_Model extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'tblusers';

    protected $fillable = ['UserName', 'EmailAddress', 'Password', 'RoleID', 'IsActive'];

    protected $hidden = ['Password', 'remember_token'];

    protected $primaryKey = "UserID";

    public function isClient() 
    {
        return $this->RoleID == \App\Enumeration\Role\RoleType::Client ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

**Below is my route.php file**

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {

    Route::get('/View-Profile', 'User\Account_Controller@ViewProfile');
    Route::get('/auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
});
```

## **Question**

Am I missing something ?

Comment: How yur `getLogout` looks like then? If it's default how do you run this method?

Comment: if you call `Auth::user()->isClient()` after `Auth::logout`, then it is possible to get *non-object* related error. however, without more information it just speculation.

Comment: Simply, check your `config/auth.php` and make sure that you configure the array of `providers` as it got inside the key `users`, a value of `'model' => App\User_Model::class,` ....
check `auth.php` file to understand more